How can I get user profile and activity data through Linkedin API?
I need to get the following data on linkedin users via API:

Full profile information
Actions: reactions, comments
Profile contacts

Please advise:

What API methods do I need to use for this?
Are there any limitations?
What permissions do I need to get and how exactly?

Also I found the API documentation, but I see there are not very clear points:
- The use of this API is restricted to those developers approved by LinkedIn and subject to applicable data restrictions in their agreements.
- You may only store data returned from the Profile API for the authenticated members with their permission. Please refer to this document for guidance on storing authenticated member data. You may never store data returned from the Profile API for members other than the authenticated member.
I tried to figure out the documentation on my own, but I was not able to understand all the nuances (see questions in the previous paragraph)
